# Display data as column headers using a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, pivot, union

My data looks like

```
EmployeeId      paycategory         value

  1             Contribution         200
  1              Salary              18000
```

I want to show the results as,

```
EmployeeId        Salary      Contribution
      1             18000           200
```

My attempt looks like,

```
select EmployeeId,paycategory,value from Reports pi  where employeeId = 1 and paycategory = 'Salary'
 union 
  select EmployeeId,paycategory,value from Reports pi where employeeId = 1 and paycategory = 'Contribution'
```

The results show as,

```
 EmployeeId      paycategory        value

  1             Contribution         200
  1              Salary              18000
```

which is the same format as the original data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to pivot your dataset:

```
select employeeid,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Salary'       then value end) salary,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Contribution' then value end) contribution
from reports
group by employeeid
```